# How to get rid of iCloud music on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 4s with iOS7 and somehow I see iCloud music which I haven't downloaded yet on my iOS device.
How can I get rid of these, I do not need to see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also have videos visible in the Video.app. You can remove them following the summary below.

If you go to:

1. Settings
2. iTunes and App Store
3. Uncheck Show All **Music** (and videos)
4. Done, they’re gone!

Answer (score 1):

If all your music is deleted locally, then go to `Settings` => `Music` => `Show All Music` and uncheck the box. This will hide all music including the purchased one stored in the cloud.